# Tools For OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es

What tools are available (preferably open source or low cost) to model objects and/or worlds in opengl-es without resorting to writing matricies of vertexes?

Comment: What are "matricies of vertexes"?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use different kinds of external tools to develop models/worlds and then just have to implement some kind of loader for the saved/exported models. Hell, i have seen people modelling their worlds with Micorsoft Visio.
I don't really encourage you to use it, but the .obj model format is a very simple format (but does not fit very well with opengles anyway) for which implementing a simple loader is not too hard.
you might want to look at [blender](http://www.blender.org) for a very good and free modeling tool that can export .obj model files and different other formats.